# onSearch method inside fragment

Tags: android, search, fragment

How can I turn this method to be used in a fragment class? I am unable to use this method in a fragment (onCreate).

```
 public void onSearch(View view) {
        EditText location_tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List<Address> addressList = null;
        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
    }
```

I do not know how the inclusion of an action through this method onSearch , the layout is ready to receive the method but do not know how to insert it in the class. I 'm trying to insert the onSearch method in this code :

```
public class FragmentC  extends Fragment{
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag4, container,
                false);
        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
        // latitude and longitude
        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

        // Changing marker icon
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // adding marker
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        // Perform any camera updates here
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroyView();
       // Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView");

        Fragment f = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (f != null) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
```

Comment: You should provide more context, because it seems that you have declared this in your Activity, but it's not clear why you would want this to be called from your fragment, what are you doing in your fragment and what is exactly you intention with this.

Comment: Thanks for helping , I edited the description, please look again. @azetaguionbajo

Comment: There I've edited the answer. That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that mMapView is the same as mMap, and that theres a button that triggers the onSearch method, here's how your Fragment code should look like. Pay attention to the onCreateView changes and that the method onSearch does not recieves a View param:

```
private EditText mLocationEditText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflat and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag4, container,
            false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    // Obtain the EditText view reference first
    mLocationEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);

    // Obtain the button that triggers the onSearch reference
    mButtonThatTriggersSearch = (Button) v..findViewById(R.id.search_button_id);
    // Set the onClickListener that should excecute when someome clicks the button
    mButtonThatTriggersSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            onSearch();
        }
    });

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 17.385044;
    double longitude = 78.486671;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    // Perform any camera updates here
    return v;
}

private void onSearch() {
    String location = mLocationEditText.getText().toString();
    List<Address> addressList = null;
    if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mLocationEditText.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
        mLocationEditText.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
}
```